# App crashes only in xcode instruments

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a strange issue, I have developed an app , I analyzed the app from Xcode i.e Xcode>Product>Analyze, then fixed any memory leaks I got. I ran the app in ipad simulator it worked fine, no crash nothing, ran it on an iPad device;no crash no errors nothing.

But when I tried to profile the app from instruments for memory leaks , during profiling there were no memory leaks, but at one stage when I load a modal view and then after Modal view dismissal the app crashes and instrument displays simulator session time out.
[image: A screenshot of the issue]
What could be the problem ?

Comment: I would recommend checking the `dealloc` method of the modal view. There may be some already deallocated objects before `dealloc` trying to send `dealloc` again.

Comment: I am not using any dealloc method in the modal view.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have any compile conditions, e.g.: `#ifdef DEBUG ...`, to switch on/off functionality between debug and release this could cause problems since Instruments uses the Release configuration and regular Simulator run uses Debug.

Comment: Thanks there were some errors when I run the App in release mode , it crashed. Resolved the issues. Thanks again