# Core plot makes my app crashes using Instruments

Tags: ios, crash, core-plot, instruments, reloaddata

My app works great with my iPhone and simulator.
I am trying to check if everything is fine with the help of Instruments (first time I'm using it !), but the app stops, without any error or leak or whatever...
It seems that core plot is the problem, especially the `reloadData` method.
I didn't find any information on this problem...
Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance !

EDIT :
It also terminates with `[graph applyTheme:theme]` and `graphHostingView.hostedGraph = graph;`

ANSWER :
I have added -ObjC in Other Linker Flags and it works great now !

Comment: Where does it stop? What Instrument are you using? Some of them can really impact application performance while they collect data behind the scenes.

Comment: Whatever instrument I use, it stops at the reloadData (core plot) method...

Comment: I run Core Plot apps under Instruments all the time. See [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679641/app-crashes-only-in-xcode-instruments) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372553/xcode-instruments-causing-app-crash) for some suggestions on things to check in your app.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Unfortunately it didn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER : I have added -ObjC in Other Linker Flags and it works great now !